# Shader map in unity

Tags: unity, fbx, unity-shader-graph

I'd created a shader graph in shader editor of unity. And I applied it to new material also. When I imported a .fbx object(box-like object and vertical slab like object) and applied that material in unity it shows simply shows yellow color only. But When I created a new object(cube which is in middle) inside the unity and applied it shows the correct pattern(red-yellow-green). I need the same pattern in the imported .fbx object also. I created that .fbx object in blender.

Please help me out.

In the shader graph in-branch node, I'm using object space.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sanp of unity]

[image: Shader graph]

Comment: Did you set up the UV maps for the object in Blender? (assuming your shader uses UVs - it looks to me like a shader which would use UVs, but you are not showing us the complete shader graph, so it might just as well use object-space or world-space coordinates)

Comment: As Philipp says, if you want us to help you debug this material, you'll need to show us how your material is working so we don't have to guess. At minimum you should include a legible screenshot of your whole graph and, if your shader uses texture coordinates, a screenshot of the UV unwrap of your model from Blender.

Comment: @Philipp and DMGreory Sorry for the inconvenience I'd attached the pic of the shader graph.

Comment: It looks like you've set your "origin" parameters so they're outside the object, so the whole object fits inside the middle yellow stripe.

Comment: Yeah, I just troubleshot that problem. Thank you. Is there any solution to change origin in unity itself. @DMGregory

Comment: You created those origin variables yourself. They're exposed in the material properties if you want to change them in the inspector.

Comment: yeah! Thank you so much!!